# Python using array elements as indices in multidimension array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm parsing results from a SOAP query (wsdl) and getting the results in an array of arrays like:

```
[(item){
   item[] =
      (item){
         key[] =
            "cdr_id",
         value[] =
            "201407000000000431",
      },
      (item){
         key[] =
            "cdr_date",
         value[] =
            "2014-07-07 07:47:12",
      },
... (snipped for brevity - 81 items in total)
      (item){
         key[] =
            "extradata",
         value[] = <empty>
      },
 }]
```

I need to extract a single value that corresponds to a particular key.
I have encountered 2 issues:

1. How to map keys to values? (Otherwise I nest for loops over `result.item[][]`)
2. How to return value as integer?

I am quite new to python, so sorry in advance if question seems too simple.

My current code looks a bit like:

```
success_calls =  client.service.selectRowset(tables[table], sfilter, None, None, None)[1]
total_time = calls_num = 0
for call in success_calls:
   for key in range(len(call.item)):
       if call.item[key][0] is "elapsed_time":
           item_value = call.item[key][1]
   total_time += int(item_value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Dictionary` for all these values to access specific values using a specific key. Dictionaries are pythons implementation of hashed tables. Note that this would only make sense if you like to access the dictionary multiple times because you need to run through your array during the creation of the hash-table and calculate a hash-value for every entry. If you only want to extract a single value, the best solution is to run through the array as you already do in your code example. In worst case you have a complexity `O(n)`.

You can easily parse a String to Integer in python using `int("12345")`. But be careful. This can raise a `ValueError` exception if your string is not parseable to integer. If your `elapsed_time` is a real number and not a natural one you can parse is using `float("22.2123")`

Comment: result of success_calls is 14 arrays, each containing 81 "items". I I iterate over 14x81 items instead of using the same dictionary, unless I don't understand how dictionaries work. In any event - I am a NOOB as far as python goes - I tried to dict(success_calls) and dict(success_calls.item) but couldn't figure out how to assign the key,value arrays. as for the last issue - the answers (at least as viewed by print item_value) is in square brackets [] - it is an integer, but because of the brackets when I try to int() it, I get no value.

Comment: 81 is hardwired - it's always the same items, different values. The number of success_calls is variable, and can reach several thousands on a busy server.

Comment: Ok, if your answer is in square brackets you only have to choose the first field to int() it... thus: int(item_value[0]). Seems like value is another array. How i just mentioned: Dictionaries are only useful (in terms of performance) if you want to access it multiple times. The interpreter have to run through the whole array and hash every single entry to create it. You said you only want to extract one single value. So the solution using nested loops should be cheaper than creating a dictionary.

Comment: You said these 81 entries are hardwired. Does the "elapsed_time"-tag also always appear at the same position in call.item? if yes you can remove the second for loop and access it directly.
e.g. if it alway appears at the 66th postion
item_value = call.item[66][1]

Comment: I already accepted this answer, but just for completeness' sake - in the end I just did item_value = call[34][1][0]